# Set permission of created directories by CreateDirectory

Tags: files-and-directories

What determines permission mask of directories created by `CreateDirectory`? Calling

```
CreateDirectory["/tmp/dir"]
```

gives directory with mask 0777 as listed by `ls` (on OSX)

```
$ ls /tmp
drwxrwxrwx  2 user  staff    68B  7 paź 22:34 dir
```

One can check default umask by calling e.g.

```
ReadList["!umask", String]
```

> `{"0000"}`

but this I'm guessing is not connected in any way to `CreateDirectory`. Calling `Run`, `ReadList` or `RunProcess` (v10) with default settings passed to `mkdir` gives also directory with 0777 mask. Is there any way of changing default mask used by `CreateDirectory`?

Comment: Did you try for example `Run["mkdir -m u=rwx,g=,o= /tmp/dir"]` ? Works for me.

Comment: no help, but a confirmation and also note if you create a file ( `Run["touch file"]` ) it gets an "all rw" mask regardless of the `umask` setting.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the `umask` is very relevant.

According to [mkdir(2)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/mkdir.2.html) system call man page (which is what `CreateDirectory` ultimately does),

> The directory *path* is created with the access permissions specified by
>        *mode* and restricted by the [umask(2)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/umask.2.html) of the calling process.

As mentioned in the question, the default *mode* is 0777. We can check the effect of `umask` -- this being OS X, it's best seen by running a standalone kernel from a terminal, so that the `umask` gets properly inherited from the parent process (`bash`).

```
$ umask 0123
$ WolframKernel
Mathematica 10.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2015 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:= d = CreateDirectory["/tmp/foo"];                                        

In[2]:= ReadString[StringJoin["!ls -ld ", d]]                                             

Out[2]= "drw-r-xr--  2 iliang  wheel  68 Oct 29 17:31 /tmp/foo"
```

(*note: I used OS X 10.10 in the above example. With OS X 10.11, the result would be as if `umask` had not been set*)

As for what happens when using the notebook interface (i.e. the kernel is launched by the frontend), there probably are ways to set a [`umask` for GUI programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27888296/set-umask-in-os-x-yosemite) on OS X, but I wasn't really tempted to try them: [SquareOne](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/19960/squareone)'s [suggestion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96436/set-permission-of-created-directories-by-createdirectory#comment261097_96436) to use something like

```
Run["mkdir -m u=rwx,g=,o= /tmp/dir"]
```

works just fine.