# Why does Mathematica use a different $PATH than terminal?

Tags: interoperability, mac-os-x, external-calls

I am trying to run bash commands from within Mathematica. Funnily enough, Mathematica seems to use a different $PATH environment than the system environment. If I try

```
Environment["PATH"]
```

or equivalently in Mathematica 10

```
RunProcess[$SystemShell, All, "echo $PATH"]
```

I get (in StandardOutput):

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

However, if I run `echo $PATH` on my (OS X) terminal, I get (both as user and root):

```
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin/:/usr/texbin:/Users/frederik/bin
```

which is indeed the full path. Why doesn't use Mathematica the same environmental variable? Is this expected behaviour?

**EDIT**

*I already mentioned in the comments why this question is different from [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63628/how-does-mathematica-use-system-environment-variables), but to avoid getting this question marked as a duplicate I'll repeat it here.*

That thread does not deal with system environment variables (it's an unfortunate wording in the topic title) but with Mathematica environment variables. The path variable for the latter is stored in `$Path` in Mathematica, while the former can be accessed by executing `Environment["PATH"]` (which gives the OS system environment path). I'm really asking about the system environment variable here, but thanks to [ilian](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/145/ilian) and [m_goldberg](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/3066/m-goldberg) I realise now that it is an OS X issue.

Comment: @dionys I've seen that one as well, but that thread does not deal with system environment variables (typo in the topic) but Mma environment variables. See the difference between `$Path` and `'PATH'`in Mma. I'm really asking about the system environment variable here, which you access with `Environment["PATH"]`.

Comment: @dionys When I run a bash command inside Mma using `Run[]` or `RunProcess[]`, it will only recognise commands inside the system wide `$PATH` variable (Unix notation). What I don't understand is why it doesn't use my system path, but seems to use some default unix path which is only part of it.

Comment: @dionys No problem, thanks for your comment :-).

Comment: The docs for `Environment` indicate the path is system dependent ... perhaps your shell sets a user-specific environment that differs from the system default? `RunProcess` also has a `ProcessEnvironment` option you can take advantage of.

Comment: I'm having this problem in Windows mathematica

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is certainly an OS X issue. Assuming the default shell is configured, when Terminal starts up it runs the script file `~/.bash_profile`, which usually modifies the PATH environment variable. You can do the same thing in *Mathematica* with

```
SetEnvironment["PATH" -> Import["!source ~/.bash_profile; echo $PATH", "Text"]]
```

After which

```
Environment["PATH"]
```

should match what you see in Terminal.

Comment: It still doesn't match up fully. After sourcing `.bash_profile`, most paths in `/opt, /usr, /bin` and `/sbin` are present, but the paths in `/opt/X11, /Library/TeX` and `/usr/texbin` are still missing. So probably OS X has another source as well for its `$PATH` variable, but I guess it's no longer a question for Mathematica.SE anymore then..

Comment: @freddieknets the other OS X source for `$PATH` is `/etc/path` and the files in `/etc/paths.d`. They are loaded by the OS X utility [`path_helper`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/path_helper.8.html).

Comment: This worked... but then didn't. Nonetheless up vote :)

Comment: *Mathematica* 11.2 under macOS Sierra (10.12.6) is *not* getting its value of `Environment["PATH"]` from `/etc/path` and the files in `/etc/paths.d`. In fact, the output from `Environment["PATH"]` is only `"/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"`; however, `/etc/path` includes the additional path `/usr/local/bin`, and on my system `/etc/paths.d` includes among others the file `TeX` containing the additional path `/Library/TeX/texbin`.

Comment: I know this question specifically mentions OS X and that it was thus pointed out that it was an OS issue. I just want to add a comment for someone who encounters this in Ubuntu that I am having the same Issue on Ubuntu 20.04 so OS X is not alone in this regard.

Answer (score 12):

I think this is an OS X issue. Note that if you launch *Mathematica* from a terminal, you will get the value of `Environment["PATH"]` which you expected.

For GUI applications that are started through Finder/LaunchServices, the environment (and `$PATH` in particular) is different and determined by the OS (this is a [related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96436) recent question that had to do with setting up `umask`).

This behavior may be [changed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51677/how-to-set-path-for-finder-launched-applications), though the exact mechanism seems to evolve with each OS X release and I don't know off the top of my head what is the best approach to achieve this on Yosemite or El Capitan.

Comment: Indeed, launching Mathematica from Terminal was the most expeditious solution for me, and it will always work. In a Terminal window, type `/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/Mathematica &`. (Leave that window open!) Then in Mathematica, you can verify that it worked with `Environment["PATH"]`.

Answer (score 5):

As noted by @ilian the easiest solution is to simply launch Mathematica from a Terminal window that has a `PATH` you like. On macOS:

```
/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/Mathematica &
```

An even easier way is to launch Mathematica by opening a notebook using the `open` command from a Terminal window:

```
open whatever.nb
```

Then that instance of Mathematica will inherit the `PATH` of that Terminal session.

Or you can set the path directly in any notebook in which you care about this, as noted by @m_goldberg. I like this solution the best, since it is the least obtrusive and you can add only what you really need, e.g.:

```
SetEnvironment["PATH" -> "/usr/local/bin:" ~~ Environment["PATH"]~~":/Users/myname/bin"]
```

If you would like to set an application path permanently on macOS, you can:

```
sudo launchctl config user path $PATH
```

and then reboot *and* restart all applications (lest they hold the old path through the reboot). That will set the path for *all* applications and *all* users to the path you have in the terminal you ran that command from.

You could instead `echo $PATH` and then copy just the parts you want into the the `launchctl` command.

This can be undone on macOS with:

```
sudo defaults delete /private/var/db/com.apple.xpc.launchd/config/user.plist PathEnvironmentVariable
```

For any solution, you can verify the path the Mathematica kernel is currently using with:

```
Environment["PATH"]
```