# Where does Mathematica get the value of Environment["PATH"] on newer version of OS X?

Tags: mac-os-x, system-variables, environment

Under macOS Sierra, at least, where does *Mathematica* (currently 11.2) get the value of `Environment["PATH"]`?

A comment to the accepted answer at [Why does Mathematica use a different $PATH than terminal?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99704/why-does-mathematica-use-a-different-path-than-terminal) seems to claim that *Mathematica* gets that value from `~/.bash_profile` along with `/etc/path` and the files in `/etc/paths.d`. That is manifestly wrong!

In fact, on my system,

```
Environment["PATH"]
```

gives output only:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

However, `/etc/path` includes the additional path `/usr/local/bin`, and `/etc/paths.d` includes among others the file `TeX` that contains the additional path `/Library/TeX/texbin`.

[I do not have any file `~/.bash_profile`, as that would preclude essential use of `~/.profile`, and the latter is where various applications, including MacPorts, append to the path. (My understanding is that if `~/.bash_profile` exists, then at least in Terminal, `~/.profile` would never be read.)

Comment: Mathematica inherits the environment from the process that starts it, just like other apps. If it is started from a terminal, it will have the value you set in the terminal (i.e. what's in your `.profile`). Otherwise, it will have the default system value, which isn't affected by `.profile`.

Comment: As for setting the system default, I think this is the relevant post: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/107787/31058 But I have never done this.

Comment: I'm always starting Mathematica.app directly from Finder, and *not* using a command in Terminal (except on rare occasions when I use the `wolframscript` command-line executable).

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the second answer to the question you linked to, this is not entirely stable from version to version in OS X.  That's under Apple's control, not ours.  It also varies based on the specifics of your shell and configuration.  For example, I use `zsh` as my shell and set the path in `.zshenv` rather than `.profile` or `.zprofile`.  I don't think that `bash` has a similar mechanism.

If you wish to ensure that Mathematica's path is identical to the Terminal's, you can launch it from the terminal by typing `/Applications/Mathematica/Contents/MacOS/Mathematica &`.  It will then inherit the value of `PATH` from your terminal rather than from Launch Services.  If you double click on Mathmeatica (or, equivalently, type `open /Applications/Mathematica.app`) then Mathematica inherits from the graphical environment, which may be different.

Comment: One could set up a new default kernel which is started through a shell script that explicitly reads the `.profile`. On OS X this will work transparently.

Comment: @Szabolcs: If I understand correctly, all this involves is to specify that shell script in the "Launch Command" field of the Kernel Configuration dialog window that opens from menu Evaluation > Kernel Configuration Options > Add and then to make that the Default Kernel. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @murray Yes.  Somewhat inconvenient, but at least it's a one-time inconvenience, and much better than starting from the command line. I saw your comments on Wolfram Community after I wrote this answer. I think the solution for that would be for J.M. to update the package, so you can configure where to look for the executable (instead of just finding it on the path).

Comment: @Szabolcs, sounds like a good idea. But it would be nice to get feedback from other Mac users first so I could get a handle on what to do here, since I can't test on a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

@Itai explained why Mathematica doesn't pick up `.profile`.

As a simple way to pick up your `.profile`, you can create a shell script for starting up Mathematica, and explicitly read `.profile` in it.  For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

source ~/.profile
/Applications/Mathematica\ 11.2.app/Contents/MacOS/MathKernel "$@"
```

Adjust the path to MathKernel on your system.  Make the script executable (e.g. from the terminal `chmod a+x yourscript.sh`)

Then create a new kernel in Evaluation -> Kernel Configuration Options, and simply replace `WolframKernel` or `MathKernel` with the full path to this script.

Comment: I do not need to pick up the entire path from `.profile` that Terminal uses! I merely want to pick up one more location, namely, `opt/local/bin`. And in any case I do *not* want to have to start `Mathematica.app` in any but the usual ways from Finder, including clicking on its icon in the Dock.

Comment: @murray I don't understand your comment. I just showed you how to set any path you want without having to start Mathematica from the terminal ... Set up the kernel to be started through a shell script that adjusts the path as you need. No terminal needed.

Comment: OK, I see now what to do, viz., just replace `~/.profile` by another file that contains my desired path. Will try. Thanks. (Still annoying, and puzzling, that *Mathematica* does not pick up the entire path as specified in `/etc/paths` and `/etc/paths.d/*`, or at least in `/etc/paths`.)

Comment: This is not working for me. The shell script you show (edited to replace `Mathematica\ 11.2.app` to just `Mathematica.app`, the name on my system), is OK, as I can run it directly from a Terminal command line and thereby start a kernel.  (continued in separate comment)

Comment: (continuation) But if in *Mathematica` Evaluation > Kernel Configuration Options...` I uncheck "Automatically launch on from end startup" the (default) `Local` kernel, add a new kernel `KernelMyPath`, in the Edit window for that click "Advanced Options", and in the "Launch command" field insert `~/bin/mma_with_path.sh` (the correct location of the script), and save; then quit *Mathematica*, restart it, and use Evaluation > Start Kernel and select that kernel, then I get a pop-up window "Kernel License Failure" saying the kernel "was not able to start due to licensing terms...."

Comment: (continuation) And to simplify things, I changed `source ~/.profile` in the script to `source ~/path_for_mma`, where file `path_for_mma` contains just the line `export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin"`. Same error.